# Unable to scrape h1 class with python/beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a title from an h1 class, but I keep getting "None"

```py
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    
title = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'prod-name'})
print(title)
```

I've also tried using this way:

```py
name_div = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'})[0]
name = name_div.find('h1').text
print(name)
```

in which case I get: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Can anybody help me out?
This is the source code:

```html
    <div class="row attachDetails __web-inspector-hidebefore-shortcut__">    
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="brand-desc">POLO RALPH LAUREN</div> 
                 <h1 class="prod-name">ARAN CREWNECK SWEATER</h1>  
                  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="borders-overview">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <label class="overview-label collapsed" data-angle="overview-label" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"> 
                               <a class="fa fa-angle-up pull-right"></a>
                               <a class="over-view">OVERVIEW</a>
                                <span class="color-disp over-view">COLOR: FAWN GREY HEATHER</span>  
                               <span class="style-num over-view">MATERIAL# : 710766783002                                                                                         
                            </span></label>                            
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="short-desc-section"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="border-details">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <label class="prod-details collapsed" data-angle="prod-details" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">                              
                               <a class="detail-link">Details</a>                               
                               <a class="fa fa-angle-up pull-right"></a>
                            </label>                                                      
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse2" class="long-desc panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div><ol><li>STANDARD FIT</li><li>COTTON</li></ol></div>
                           <ol>
                             <div><li><b>Board:</b> S196SC23</li></div>  
                             <!--***********************************************************************************************************-->
                         </ol> 
                      </div>
                    </div>                  
                  </div>                     
             </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
```